# save all POST information mongodb

Tags: mongodb, post

I am having a small issue saving al POST fields into MongoDB

```
function savedata($data){
        $collection = $this->db->retail_logs;
        $this->data = json_decode($data);


        try {
        $collection->update(
            array("tradingname"=>$this->data['tradingname']),
            $this->data, "date"=> date("d.m.Y"), "time"=>date("H:i:s"),"whochanged"=>$_COOKIE['CRMUIDkey']), // new lead document to insert
            array("upsert" => true, "safe" => true)
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Something went wrong .. 
        }
    }
```

For some reson the $this->data which holds the $_POST does not want to go there i get this error

```
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/crmvip/public_html/system/db/mongo.php on line 294

Warning: MongoCollection::update() expects at most 3 parameters, 4 given in /home/crmvip/public_html/system/db/mongo.php on line 302
```

it sends the POST information like it should `tradingname=monkey&street=abc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is for decoding JSON.

If you just want to save value of `data` received through a POST request:

```
   $this->data = $_POST['data'];
```